Replicate CHSH tutorial with Aer GPU simulator
I am new to Qiskit.
I am trying to replicate the CHSH tutorial but using Aer Simulator with an Nvidia GPU.
To do so, I first have to replace
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum")
backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False, min_num_qubits=127)

with
from qiskit_aer import AerProvider, AerSimulator

provider = AerProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend('aer_simulator_tensor_network_gpu', 
    # method='tensor_network', device='GPU', 
    runtime_parameter_bind_enable=True
)

Then, in accordance with some Aer tutorials, once must replace the CHSH's tutorial's
... # Please refer to the actual demonstration

pub = (
    chsh_isa_circuit,  # ISA circuit
    [[isa_observable1], [isa_observable2]],  # ISA Observables
    individual_phases,  # Parameter values
)

job_result = estimator.run(pubs=[pub]).result()

with something such as
simulator = AerSimulator(method='tensor_network', device='GPU')

... 

def compile_circ():
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
    circuit.h(0)
    circuit.cx(0, 1)
    circuit.ry(theta, 0)
    return circuit
    
circ = compile_circ()
circ = transpile(circ, simu)
job_result = simulator.run(
    [circ],
    shots=100, 
    parameter_binds=[{theta: individual_phases}],
    memory=False
).result()

However, I am not certain how to apply the observables and parameter bindings properly, as there is no simulator.run(pubs=[pub]) like that from EstimatorV2.
Thereafter, since I am using memory=False, I notice that data kwarg of job_result is empty too, and there isn't much for me to plot.
The Aer Simulator works with GPU because trying https://learning.quantum.ibm.com/course/fundamentals-of-quantum-algorithms/quantum-query-algorithms with shots = 1 and memory=True does work.

Edit 1
Using qiskit_aer.primitives.EstimatorV2 to replace the tutorial's qiskit.EstimatorV2 has not been very successful; i.e. replacing
estimator = Estimator(mode=backend)
...
job_result = estimator.run(pubs=[pub]).result()

with
from qiskit_aer.primitives import EstimatorV2 as Estimator
...
estimator = Estimator(options={"backend_options":{'method':'tensor_network', 'device':'GPU'}})
...
job_result = estimator.run(pubs=[pub]).result()

defaults to what feels like a CPU backend.

References:
https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit-ibm-runtime/qiskit_ibm_runtime.EstimatorV2
https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/stubs/iskit_aer.primitives.EstimatorV2.html
